# Scroll to Anchor from different page without # in URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hash

I need a little help. I was trying to do is when I'm on **Page1.html** then I click the **<a href="Page2.html">** it will scroll down like this **animate({scrollTop: $("#Id-on-Page2").offset().top - 100}**  to the **ID/Class** on **Page2.html**. I know I can use this **Page2.html#Id-on-Page2** but I want to achieve is to **remove** the **#Anchor** on **URL.**

The only thing I did was when you were on Page1.html when I click a-href or btn it will scroll without **ID on URL** or **#Anchor**.

```
    $('.Page1-ahref').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".Id-on-Page1").offset().top - 100
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: You're going to have to store a bit of data somewhere so that page2 knows what it's supposed to do. (Note that what you want prevents proper bookmarking.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onClick event store `ID` of the element you want to scroll to in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Then, check `localStorage` on page load and scroll to the stored element if it exists.

Here is a quick example:

```js
$('.Page1-ahref').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // store desired id
    localStorage.setItem("scrollTo", ".Id-on-Page1");
});


// check if we need to scroll on page load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  const _scrollTo = localStorage.getItem("scrollTo")
  if (_scrollTo) {
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(_scrollTo).offset().top - 100
    }, 0);
  }
  // clean up
  localStorage.removeItem("scrollTo");
});
```

Comment: It works Thank you! I will remember that localStorage, +1 intelligent :)